# Will be there  issues when upgrading from Kohana3?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, backwards-compatibility

I would like to know about the compatibility between upcoming versions of KO3. I have heard that once 3.1 comes in, it won't be easy to simply upgrade to it from kohana 3.0 (Wordpress upgrade is pretty swift from 2 to version 3)

If I create my project in KO3 (currently using 3.0.6.2), what are the chances that my project will be easily upgradable to 3.1 or above versions without breaking anything ?

Please answer if you are a real pro on KO3 or part of the development team.. This is important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Major versions (eg: 3.0 to 3.1) may change the API. Currently, the biggest API change will be splitting the `Request` class into `Request` and `Response`, as well as changes to `Request` that allow external routing. This also implies that the `Remote` class will be significantly modified to removed completely in favor of external requests and responses.

You can keep track of the changes scheduled for 3.1 by following the [3.1 roadmap](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/versions/show/130).

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to point out that wordpress is an entirely different system, it's basically an application written on their own framework whereas kohana is just the framework and you supply the application.

If the wordpress core framework changes then they also change their application to account for those modifications.  Sometimes plugins aren't compatible across upgrades so the plugin author has to release an update which makes it compatible.  All of this is hidden from the front end users, they don't need to be aware of how it works in order to use it.

Kohana on the other hand has no gui or front end, you're getting nitty gritty with the code.  If an interface changes then you'll have to adapt your implementation to suit, there's no way around that.

And as antpaw said, unit tests are always useful for making sure things work as expected! For more info see the [unittest repo](http://github.com/kohana/unittest)

Comment: Good one, Matt. Explains the wordpress swift upgrade nicely.

Answer (score 1):

it highly depends on the features your have used. give it a try and watch your logs or even better: you run unittests. http://github.com/kohana/core/compare/3.1...master if i picked the right repository. this will help you to see the difference betwenn ko3.1 and ko3.0.7

Comment: Can you be more elaborate on the part 'features you have used' ?
I have seen the differences myself but that does not explain whether upgrading will be an issue or not ..